# earthquake program writing to a csv file

Tags: python

Okay I am writing a program in Python. Im just trying to figure out why its not writing to the csv file right? It writes to it but only the last line of the output. I tried even writing to a text file but the same result.I need help understanding why its not printing all the output.

Here is what i did.

```
import csv
#import copy
def main():
    Moderate = []
    Strong= []
    Major=[]
    Great=[]
    Overall=[]
    Region=[]

    infile=open("earthquakes.txt", "r")


    infile.readline()
    for line in infile:
        line=line.strip().split('\t')

        if line[6] not in Region:
            Region.append(line[6])

        if float(line[1]) >=8:

            Great.append(1)
        else:
            Great.append(0)
        if float(line[1])>=7 and float(line[1])<=7.9:
            Strong.append(1)
        else:
            Strong.append(0)
        if float(line[1])>=6 and float(line[1])<=6.9:
            Major.append(1)
        else:
            Major.append(0)

        if float(line[1])>=5 and float(line[1])<=5.9:
            Moderate.append(1)
        else:
            Moderate.append(0)

        #print(len(Region),len(Moderate),len(Great),len(Major),len(Strong))
    else:
        i=Region.index(line[6])

        if float(line[1]) >=8:
            Great[i]+=1 
        if float(line[1])>=7 and float(line[1])<=7.9:
            Strong[i]+=1   
        if float(line[1])>=6 and float(line[1])<=6.9:
            Major[i]+=1
        if float(line[1])>=5 and float(line[1])<=5.9: 
            Moderate[i]+=1




  for i in range(len(Region)):

    str1=str(Region[i])+","
    str1+=str(Moderate[i])+","
    str1+=str(Major[i])+","
    str1+=str(Great[i])+","
    str1+=str(Strong[i])+","
    Overall=Moderate[i]+Major[i]+Great[i]+Strong[i]
    str1+=str(Overall)
    #print(Overall)
    print(str1)
    cvsFile=open("earthquake.cvs",'w')
    # for i in range(len(Region)):
    words=['Region,Great,Major,Strong,Moderate,Overall']

    w=csv.writer(cvsFile,delimiter=' ')

    w.writerows(words) 
    cvsFile.write(str1)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Try with `cvsFile=open("earthquake.cvs",'a')`. Otherwise it overwrites your file at each row

Comment: also you don't need to open your file in your loop...

Comment: and is it cvsFile or csvFile (comma separeted values?)

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you need to work more on this code but try this:

```
with open('earthquake.csv', 'a') as csvFile:
    for i in range(len(Region)):
        str1 = ','.join([Region[i], Moderate[i], Major[i], Great[i], Strong[i], ''])
        Overall = ''.join[Moderate[i], Major[i], Great[i], Strong[i]]
        str1 += Overall
        # print(Overall)
        # print(str1)

        words = ['Region,Great,Major,Strong,Moderate,Overall']

        w = csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter=' ')
        w.writerows(words)

        csvFile.write(str1)
```